# Codeigniter ORMs functionality equivalents

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm

There are some functionalities in ORMs which is very good, but I couldn't find any equivalents in CodeIgniter. Let me tell the problem. When I want to write a join query (e.g. users join comments) the output is something like this:

```
[
    user_id:1,
    payment_id:1
],
[
    user_id:1,
    payment_id:2
],
[
    user_id:2,
    payment_id:3
],
[
    user_id:2,
    payment_id:4
],
```

The thing I want to achieve is something like this:

```
[
    user_id: 1,
    payments: [
        [
            payment_id:1
        ],
        [
            payment_id:2
        ],
    ]
],
[
    user_id: 2,
    payments: [
        [
            payment_id:3
        ],
        [
            payment_id:4
        ],
    ]
],
```

The same thing that I've done in `sequalize` ORM:

```
return Users.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Payments,
        as: "payments"
    }]
})
```

Comment: I believe to achieve that you'll need two separate queries, one to select all users, second to select payment details of each users.

Comment: No, I don't want to make a loop and have too many queries.

Comment: Okay, you don't want to, but you are looking for a ready to use solution which, probably, uses loop to give the result you want.